# Customize toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-jetpack

I have  single  activity  and  many fragments, in  my  main  activity I have a toolbar, what I need  is  set  different  toolbar  per  fragment

```
findNavController(nav_host_fragment).addOnNavigatedListener { controller, 
 destination ->
 when(destination.id) {
    R.id.destination1 -> {
        //Do something 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a Toolbar in your activity at all if every Fragment has its own Toolbar?

Comment: suppose  ,  I need to implement collapsing toolbar  on one of my fragment  and  and leave  other work with  main activity  (single) toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not intuitive to have more than one toolbar on display at a single time. But, in any case, for that go to styles.xml and ensure that the app theme has the parent `"ThemeOverlay.Appcompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`. Next, in the layouts for your fragments, make whatever toolbar you want to make.